# Can we report / do anything about a persistent troll?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, trolling, multiple-accounts

First of all, please note the precedent: [Dealing with persistent trolls: “see the newsgroups guy”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2520/dealing-with-persistent-trolls-see-the-newsgroups-guy)   - Jeff himself has posted about a similarly troublesome account.  This is also tangentially related to [What's the SO policy about having multiple user accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/whats-the-so-policy-about-having-multiple-user-accounts)

Check this guy out:  [Erwin Smout](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=erwin+smout+site%3Astackoverflow.com%2Fusers&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)  (no rhyme intended)

Over 9 **pages** of user accounts registered.  It looks like some have already been deleted, but type his name into the user search on SO right now and you'll see a full page of results, so there are at least 35 *current* accounts.

Let me be clear about this, I am *very* apprehensive about complaining about a *specific* user and would *never* start this type of discussion if I didn't think it was an extreme case.  People argue on SO (and probably the other trilogy sites), it's natural, and sometimes they get heated and/or spill over onto Meta - I'm not upset or offended by conflict, but this user's outbursts are completely random and unprovoked and usually off on a tangent, and I honestly think that the only logical conclusion here is that he/she/it is a serial troll.

---

Some of his answers (and note that these are all coming from *different* accounts):

- [How can I write this query in Django? (datetime)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551475/how-can-i-write-this-query-in-django-datetime/2556632#2556632)
  <sub>Here he blasts the OP for "not knowing how to get anything done in Django" and picking the wrong tool, apparently.</sub>
- [Why isn’t “String or Binary data would be truncated” a more descriptive error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547592/why-isnt-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-a-more-descriptive-error/2548559#2548559)
  <sub>This one is a random rant about error messages which has almost nothing to do with the question.</sub>
- [Should I use a huge composite primary key or just a unique id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517649/should-i-use-a-huge-composite-primary-key-or-just-a-unique-id/2519805#2519805)
  <sub>Another tirade, this time about surrogate keys, complete with cursing and anti-religion overtones.</sub>
- [The Integrity of linked data entities on update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127530/the-integrity-of-linked-data-entities-on-update/2141837#2141837)
  <sub>Here he goes way off-topic, answering a question that the OP didn't ask.</sub>
- [What is the standard or best way to deal with database branching with Mercurial or Git branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517760/what-is-the-standard-or-best-way-to-deal-with-database-branching-with-mercurial-o/2520092#2520092)
  <sub>Not so inflammatory this time but basically a non-answer, "you can't do it".</sub>
- [How to Delete all data from a table which contain self referencing foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483154/how-to-delete-all-data-from-a-table-which-contain-self-referencing-foreign-key/2483221#2483221)
  <sub>A less-useful (and wrong) duplicate of another answer, posted later.  I wonder who gave him the 1 upvote.</sub>
- [Are there Database Systems more suited to Social Networks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610506/are-there-database-systems-more-suited-to-social-networks/1610667#1610667)
  <sub>"The idiot who wrote this doesn't understand jack shit about the power of relational algebra." (Scary that this answer actually got 4 upvotes).</sub>
- [How do I store (and sort) vague date ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378873/how-do-i-store-and-sort-vague-date-ranges/2418513#2418513)
  <sub>Basically a massive long-winded explanation of how what the OP wanted to do was impossible.  Posted 6 days **after** Quassnoi gave a perfectly serviceable answer that received 6 upvotes and an accept.</sub>
- [Duplicate domain constraints in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265989/duplicate-domain-constraints-in-table/2275809#2275809)
  <sub>In here he basically says, several times, that everybody else is an idiot.</sub>
- [What is the difference between graph-based databases and object-oriented databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218118/what-is-the-difference-between-graph-based-databases-and-object-oriented-database/2224928#2224928)
  <sub>A rather pointless and unsubstantiated knock against OODBs.</sub>
- [Do relational databases provide a feasible backend for a process historian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195234/do-relational-databases-provide-a-feasible-backend-for-a-process-historian/2203962#2203962)
  <sub>Cursing and complaining about all the "mediocre" programmers.</sub>

---

So to summarize, we have someone who:

- Answers with a combination of circumlocution, flowery prose, and four-letter words, typically only to explain that the question author is an idiot or that it's impossible to do what he's asking;
- Creates new accounts every day, sometimes multiple times per day, so it's not even worth the rep cost to downvote;
- Repeatedly posts comments as answers **and even acknowledges that he's doing it and that it's frowned upon**, but apparently doesn't seem to care.
- Actually has one account that's accrued over 500 rep (mostly from one-off upvotes), so he clearly knows *how* to register properly and even provide useful answers once in a while, but seems to create these rather obvious sockpuppet accounts to troll.
- Is submitting these troll answers to questions **that are not even remotely controversial!**

I suppose it's *possible* that whoever this is is creating all these accounts simply can't figure out how to use the login system properly, but seems more likely to me that he's creating throwaway accounts in order to escape culpability (downvotes) from his troll posts.

---

Thoughts?  Does my theory make sense?  Is it reasonable to want to do something about this, or am I making mountains out of molehills?  Assuming it's a reasonable complaint, can something be done about it, and is it appropriate to bring up the subject here on Meta?

Comment: Dude, you should totally drop whatever you're doing in Django and use JQuery.

Comment: Seriously, nice piece of research! If I can do something with my brand shiny new 10k super-powers that I was so far mostly reluctant to flex, tell me what the guidelines/rules are and i'll be glad to help

Comment: @ChristopheD, he seems to have worked at the Ippa bank for 15 years and two months and at the ippa bank for 16 years and had a two years education at St Lodewijk.

Comment: I went through and deleted a few of the more inflammatory "answers" so those won't show up for everybody.  I can't really justify deleting an answer for simply being wrong, so please just downvote any that are incorrect.

Comment: @Bill: Of course, I would not expect a post to get deleted or even flagged for being wrong or off-topic; there were varying degrees of "badness", some included only as perceived evidence of a pattern so that others could judge the facts for themselves.  Actually, I wasn't expecting *anything* to get deleted, so thanks for taking quick action; every little bit helps.

Comment: @json: I'm scared to ask where you found that... last thing I want is this question showing up at the top of a Google search for somebody's real name (this is one reason I don't use my real name!)  Should I maybe edit the parts (well, part) of this question that include the name?

Comment: @Aaronaught - probably linkedIn/Google/other social networking crap. It's downright scary how much personal info can be obtained from those (one reason I'm seriously contemplating removing my LinkedIn account and never even considered having Facebook/MySpace/other such things and never use my real name on SO

Comment: P.S. Wonder if you put in more work in tracking this down than I put into tag hierarchy War and Piece... errr ... proposal (that was a couple of hours of writing, for comparison :) )

Comment: Oh and P.S. to other readers, don't start thinking I go around digging for dirt on other users... was more a case of, I happened to notice what I thought was a trollish pattern, pulled up the profile to see if these were balanced with more "helpful" answers, saw that there was only 1 post which made no sense, and then the whole mystery started unraveling by itself.  I don't want to imply that I am encouraging grudges or elitism - *extreme* cases only, in this case I just saw a *lot* of inflammatory posts and very few upvotes.

Comment: Lol @DVK, I'm sure it looks like more effort went into this than really did, it wasn't more than 20-30 minutes, because the realization was passive, I wasn't looking for people to indict. :P

Comment: Perhaps his 500+ account has benefited from some upvotes from his legion accounts.  There must be some people quietly building rep from dummy accounts.

Comment: @dvk: http://www.google.com/search?q=erwin-smout

Comment: Huh.  Apparently connected to a number of militant anti-SQL academics.  Puts some of this into perspective, but everybody should be held to the same standards of discourse regardless, doesn't matter if you're a lowly freshman or Stroustrup himself.

Comment: @Aaronaught - Stroustrup trolls on SO? Wow! :)))

Comment: @DVK: Hey, anything's possible. Somebody's got to answer all those *why doesn't C++ have garbage collection* questions, maybe they're all his sockpuppets!

Comment: @DVK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871354/bjarnes-new-book-anyone-done-the-exercises/887999#887999

Comment: @Aaronaught - whaddaya mean C++ does not have garbage collection? Sure it does! Oh... you mean other than the DIY kind :(   )sorry, couldn't resist - I grew up on C and regard non-manual garbage collection as effete luxury :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really probably should have been an email to team@stackoverflow.com.  I know it's way too much information to succinctly put in a flag for moderator attention, so I understand why you bypassed that option.  We sort of frown on singling people out in a negative way here on meta, though.

That being said, I do appreciate you bringing this to our attention and pulling all of this information together.  I'll be merging these accounts soon.  We (the moderators) will decide what action to take once we can see the entire body of work in one place.

Comment: Understood, I wasn't previously aware that the e-mail address was intended for that, and part of me figured that this kind of thing should be given a public hearing to weed out any personal bias I might have been harbouring.  But I'll remember that for next time (if there is a next time, these occurrences seem rare).  If you want to close the question and/or edit out the personal information then I'll understand.

Comment: @Bill - you're going to JOIN all this evil??? And then people start wondering where Skynet started from!!! (me running for the bunker)

Comment: @Aaronaught: He does seem to be trolling us pretty hard, so I completely understand why you brought it up.  I'll let Jeff decide what to do with Erwin and this question itself.

Comment: @DVK: The bunker should be safe, just don't get on the submarine. ;)

Comment: @Bill - was that some veiled reference to T4? (I didn't bother seeing that yet, but I doubt it has any truly spoiler-prone secrets :) )

Comment: @DVK: Yes, that was a T4 reference.  There are one or two spoiler-prone secrets, but they're pretty easy to guess.  You were probably right to wait and rent it.

Comment: @Bill, I'm just arriving at this question for the first time, and the Google link already has five pages of results for Erwin's name again. It seems that there are at least four active accounts at this moment.

Comment: @Pop: Thanks.  I had merged over 50 accounts back when this question was new.  It looks like time to do it again before it gets out of control.  Looking at the history, I'm not the only one that's done some merging.  :(

Answer (score 1):

Down voting and flagging for a moderator's attention is the best way in my opinion to deal with someone like this.

> Thoughts? Does my theory make sense?
>   Is it reasonable to want to do
>   something about this, or am I making
>   mountains out of molehills? Assuming
>   it's a reasonable complaint, can
>   something be done about it, and is it
>   appropriate to bring up the subject
>   here on Meta?

Per the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq)

> What kind of questions can I ask
>   here?
>
> If your question is about:
>
> ```
> * Stack Overflow
> * Server Fault
> * Super User
> ```
>
> ... it is welcome here. No question is
>   too trivial or too "newbie".
>
> Please look around to see if your
>   question has already been asked (and
>   maybe even answered!) before you ask.
>   If you end up asking a question that
>   has been asked before, that is OK and
>   deliberately allowed. Other users will
>   hopefully edit in links to related or
>   similar questions to help future
>   visitors find their way.

Comment: @Josh K: The problem is that there are 30, 50, 100 separate accounts doing this.  Aside from running out of flags, it's not entirely clear that moderators will see the pattern of behaviour or know to check for sockpuppet accounts.  I could leave a comment in the "flag for moderator attention" - but what should I write so that it doesn't come across as merely vindictive?  I definitely wouldn't want to encourage frivolous "this user is a troll" flags, subsequently wasting moderators' time; coming here with "proof" seemed more appropriate, so that they don't have to be the ones to dig.

Comment: @Aaron: In that case you bring the problem here. Kudos for the write up by the way. Proper links, formatting, etc. Must have taken a while.

Answer (score 1):

For a case as extreme as this one, I think posting to MSO is the right thing.  A mod will see it here.  A flag on one of his posts would have been fine, as would an email to the dev team, linked from the bottom of each of the trilogy sites' home pages.  Your research will save the mods some time, though.

This case is fairly egregious, though I can't really see the motivation behind it (vs. simply posting from one account).  Might be someone being annoying for its own sake.  Regardless, you're not even close to crossing any ethical/other lines with your post.